# Hard disk clicks

Tags: hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on Dell Vostro laptop. The device has also Windows 7 and I set it as dual boot.

Recently, I found that when I put the laptop to sleep, the hard disk refused to resume and there are serious clicks.

Now, I hear these clicks when the laptop is booting and it refused to boot. I shut it down and try many times until it boots. Once the device is working, I don't hear any clicks.

Please help

Dina

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware failure of your hard drive, probably failing to spin up because of a bearing, motor, or some other mechanical problem.  Backup all of your important data immediately if you have not done so.

Once backed up, you will need to remove the hard drive and replace it, or take it to someone who can do it for you.

It might be possible to do a dd bit copy of the entire drive to an external drive if you have one large enough, and then bit copy the drive back again when it is fixed to get up and running as quickly as possible.  Regardless, you should a normal backup of your data in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Back up your data. Determine the make of your HDD, go to their website and download their HDD check-up tool and find out the state of your HDD. This should then give you a good idea which step to take next.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find any faults in the hard disk using Dell utility.